# Help reading Husserl?

Tags: reference-request, husserl

Does anyone have reading/comprehension tips and tricks for reading Husserl in pdf format? I've tried highlighting and summary notes on the sides but, its not enough. I don't feel like I'm able to hold all of his processes and concepts.

Comment: See e.g. [Routledge Philosophy Guidebook to Husserl and the Cartesian Meditations](https://books.google.it/books?id=0TvsXJMD-QwC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy. Could you be more specific about the text that you are attempting to read and what you aim to achieve. The practical tip  I would suggest would be to print the text and start scrawling on the print out; when it becomes too messy, print a new copy and transfer the valuable (re)marks from the previous. There are many helpful introductions to phenomenology in general but the important point is to understand that it is a *method*, not a doctrine.

Comment: Also, free availability in PDF usually means it is an old translation, which generally make a worse job in getting the details right than recent ones. Reading any of the more famous philosophers (especially German and contemporary French ones) in translation always is a messy thing, and pretty hopeless without secondary literature or supervised lecture groups where you can discuss things. At least if you do not have an extensive background due to accounts from later authors or lectures etc before.

Comment: I did not realize before today that this philosopher, Landgrebe,  was Husserl’s personal assistant. I have not read this. I just found it today. “The phenomenology of Edmund Husserl : six essays
by Landgrebe, Ludwig, 1902-1991”. At Internet Archive.

Comment: I don’t really understand why there are 3 votes to close?  Maybe if the OP put the reference request tab that would help?

Comment: @Gordon thanks, added. And thanks for the suggestions to all previous users who answered!

Answer (score 0):

They do those dictionaries for everyone. Thing is, I would advise using them to check if you've misunderstood a term, rather than to understand a term (especially if it hasn't baffled you yet), if you don't want to give yourself the mere impression of philosophical lucidity. Last time I picked up - and closely read - a great work of philosophy, The Cartesian Meditations, I was struck by how much Husserl wasn't just talking to those who had spent decades picking apart his work (though the Logical Investigations, especially, are apt for that), but for even the casual listener, supposing he or she is capable of parsing sentences and reconstructing more than language - reasons to *believe*. I recall Descartes turning up, but in less than marginal works you aren't expected to know why - that will be defined by the clever author - beyond the fact that Descartes is not to be dismissed as a fraud right away.

Philosophy can be difficult, and not just as a creative act but also being able to e.g. summarise (a pithy reading is actually quite difficult to produce - assuming you don't mean rewriting someone else's; such is analysis... you can find three minute Kant/Locke/etc. on youtube, though I could not vouch for their reliability - clarity too), but it is no more difficult to *read* than e.g. literary criticism - which also has technical terms, e.g. 'abjection', and so on. Reading *deconstruction* is weird for me cos I struggle to work out why actually the author believes their main point, but then it's the more hermeneutical approach, a never ending series of citations rather than conclusions.

Anyway, hope that helps a little: don't over think the wrong things - as no-one's trying to confuse.

### If something doesn't make sense, then be more charitable.